# How to show a text in a div by react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm going to to click in div and show a text in another div in multiple items.

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.The code will be done up to `handelrule = ((e,element,i) =>{`. There is an onClick function ({e => this.handelrule(e,element,i)}) for each item. By clicking it the text of div by class=text should change to 'test' but it does not change.

```
     class App extends React.Component {
       constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
           data: [],
           OtherRooms:{},
           divVisibles:{},
           loadingVisible:{},
           resultruleRoom:{},
         };
      }

     render() {
     const { data} = this.state;
     const renderHotel = data.map((item, i) => {
     return   <div class="item">
               <div class="moreInfo"  onClick={(e) => this.showDiv(e,item,i)}><span>show more data</span></div>
               <div key={i} className={`${!this.state.loadingVisible[i] ? "unvisible" : "visible"}`}>
                <div id="ballsWaveG">
                <div id="ballsWaveG_1" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_2" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_3" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_4" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_5" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_6" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_7" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
                <div id="ballsWaveG_8" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
             </div>
           </div>

                 <div id="box-info"  key={i} className={` ${!this.state.divVisibles[i] ? "unvisible" : "visible"}`}>
                 <div class="table">
                 {this.state.OtherRooms[i]}
                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>


     });




     return (
     <div>
     {renderHotel}
     </div>
     );
     }

     showDiv = (e,element,i) =>{
     var mainprovider=element.id.provider
     var optionId=element.families[0].optionId
        this.showLoading(e,element,i);
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('/showAllRooms.bc', {
             method: 'POST',
             body: 'mainprovider='+JSON.stringify(mainprovider)+'&optionId='+optionId+''
          },)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
 var Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    DetailsRoom: {
     ...prevState.DetailsRoom,
    [i]: this.renderDetailsRoom(Maindata, i),
  },
  divVisibles: { ...prevState.divVisibles, [i]: !prevState.divVisibles[i] },
 loadingVisible: { ...prevState.loadingVisible, [i]: "" }
 }))
}).catch(error => console.error(error))

     }, 1000); 

     }
     renderDetailsRoom(DetailsRoom,i){
     let lenfamilies = DetailsRoom.families.length 
     var indents =[];
         var index=0;
     for(var j = 0 ;j <lenfamilies;j++){
         var numF = i;
         var numS = j;
         var stingF = numF.toString();
         var stingS = numS.toString();
         index= stingF+stingS
         indents.push(<div>
                         <span>{this.renderruleRoom(DetailsRoom,DetailsRoom.families[j],j,index)}</span>
           <div key={index} className={`${!this.state.loadingVisible[index] ? "unvisible" : "visible"}`}>
             <div id="ballsWaveG">
               <div id="ballsWaveG_1" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
               <div id="ballsWaveG_2" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
               <div id="ballsWaveG_3" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
               <div id="ballsWaveG_4" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
               <div id="ballsWaveG_5" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
               <div id="ballsWaveG_6" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
               <div id="ballsWaveG_7" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
              <div id="ballsWaveG_8" class="ballsWaveG"></div>
           </div>
        </div>

     <div  key={index}>{this.state.resultruleRoom[index]}</div>
     </div>

         )
     }
     return(
       indents
       )
     }

     showLoading = (e,elem,val) => {
     this.setState( prevState => ({
     loadingVisible: { ...prevState.loadingVisible, [val]: !prevState.loadingVisible[val] }
     })) 
     };

     renderruleRoom(DetailsRoom,DetailsRoomJ,j,index){
     return <span class="txtRul"  onClick={e => this.handelruleRoom(e,DetailsRoom,DetailsRoomJ,j,index)}>قوانین اتاق</span>
     }
     handelruleRoom = (e,DetailsRoomJ,j,index) =>{
     var mainprovider=DetailsRoomJ.id.provider
     var optionId=DetailsRoomJ.optionId
     if(mainprovider==undefined){
     return ''
     }else{
     this.showLoading(e,DetailsRoomJ,index);
      /////the loading whould not be shown //////
     setTimeout(() => {
     var return_rule = function () {
     var tmp = null;
     $.ajax({
     'async': false,
     'type': "POST",
     'global': false,
     'dataType': 'html',
     'url': "rulerooms.bc",
     'data': {'mainprovider': JSON.stringify(mainprovider),'optionId':optionId, },
     'success':(response)=>{
      tmp = response;
     }
     });

     return tmp;
     }();
     return  this.setState( prevState => ({
     resultruleRoom: { ...prevState.resultruleRoom, [index]: return_rule}, ///In this part return_rule does not set in resultruleRoom ////
     loadingVisible: { ...prevState.loadingVisible, [index]: "" }
     })) 

     }, 1000); 
     }

     }

     }
     ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign a handle to each item if they do the same thing. Just change the text using `setState`.

```
<div className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({ resultrule: 'test' })></div>
<div className="text" key={i}>{this.state.resultrule}</div>
```

Also, in JSX you have to use `className` instead of `class`.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Comment: Hi @herodrigues. but I have a trouble with the text of this div what should be test in this line: `resultrule: { ...prevState.resultrule, [i]:'test'}`

Comment: But they do not  the same thing.  `test` will be changed for each item:|. I write test  For example

Comment: Could you please edit your question by formatting the code and adding an example?

Answer (score 0):

If value's are changing dynamically,you have to use handleChange() function and need to bind it.

```
 export default class RilwayForm extends React.Component{
constructor (props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
Data=[]
}
this.handleDataChange = this.handleDataChange.bind(this);
}
handleDataChange (event) {this.setState({ Data: event.target.value });}
}
```

now you can use it by calling the function.